# Conceptual differences between the notations $\int_{a}^{b}f$ and $\int_{[a,b]}f$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, soft-question

Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

What are the conceptual differences between the two notations $\int_{a}^{b}f$ and $\int_{[a,b]}f$?

[This article](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf) refers to the first one as a signed integral and the latter one an unsigned integral.

Comment: I think $\int_{[a,b]} f$ requires the notion of integral over a set.

Comment: $\int_{[a,b]} f\,dx$ is usually taken as a synonym for $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$. However, this only works if $a\le b$. There is no set $S$ such that $\int_S f\,dx = \int_3^2 f(x)\,dx$ for all functions $f$.

Comment: Yes, @CarlHeckman, I know that. I feel insecure if I missed something essential, so I asked it here to solicit deep answers if any.

Comment: By the way, if it is that simple then why did Terence Tao separate it from each other? I am not sure.

Comment: The distinction will be made clear when the Jacobian in the change of variables formula takes on an absolute value in the unsigned case. This is a point of confusion for most undergrad analysis students and highlights the difference between integrating over a set and over an oriented line segment in $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: @Nitin, thank you, I believe I know what you would like to say. But, because I have never taken any undergraduate analysis course, I am formally not an undergraduate analysis student in the canonical, standard sense :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd explain it in the following way:

**1.** The expression
$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x$$
denotes a limit of *Riemann sums*:
$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x:=\lim_{\ldots}\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)\>\mu(I_k)\ ,$$
whereby we have  partitions of $[a,b]$ into subintervals $I_k$ of length $\mu(I_k)$ in mind. This idea can immediately be transported to a higher-dimensional setting: If, e.g., $B\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is a ball then it makes sense to consider
$$\int_B f({\bf x})\>{\rm d}({\bf x}):=\lim_{\ldots}\sum_{k=1}^N f(\xi_k)\>\mu(B_k)\ ,$$
where we have partitions of $B$ into small pieces $B_k$ of volume $\mu(B_k)$ in mind. Note that lengths and volumes are just nonnegative numbers and have no inherent "orientation" or "direction".

**2.** On the other hand we have learnt to differentiate and to "integrate" functions $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. Given such an $f$ the set of functions $F$ such that $F'=f$ is completely determined by $f$ and is denoted (for whatever reasons$\ldots$) by $$\int f(x)\>dx\ .$$ After we have found one such *primitive* $F$ of $f$ we know all of them, and we could denote this set as well by $\langle F\rangle$, or similar. It so happens that time and again we have to deal with differences $F(v)-F(u)$ even before we know   $F$ explicitly. To handle this in a swift way we introduce the following notation: Given any two points $u$ and $v$ in the domain of $f$ the expression
$$\int_u^v f(x)\>dx$$
is called the *definite integral* of $f$ from $u$ to $v$, and denotes the difference $F(v)-F(u)$, computed with any primitive $F$ of $f$. Apart from the definition of derivative there are no limits involved in this setup, and formulas like
$$ \int_u^v f(x)\>dx=-\int_v^u f(x)\>dx,\quad \int_{\phi(u)}^{\phi(v)} f(x)\>dx=\int_u^v f\bigl(\phi(t)\bigr)\>\phi'(t)dt$$
are immediate.

The connection between these two streams of thought is the following: If $a<b$ then
$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)\>{\rm d}x\ =\ \int_a^b f(x)\>dx\ .$$
This is not a tautology, but a total miracle, and is called the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*.

Comment: Thank you, Prof. Blatter. I am expecting an answer like this one. I understood merely one facet of the FTC. Your exposition is helpful to me (and I believe to many).

Comment: It scratches where it itches :)

Comment: Could you please let me know whether there is any author of Analysis adopts also your point of view on the FTC? So that I may dig out more stuff that may not be mentioned in the mainstream analysis books.

Comment: @Chou: This is not "my point of view", but see here:  https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Analysis_9.pdf  (in German). It was amusing for me to learn that Tao in his notes had come almost verbatim to the same explanations.

Comment: Thank you, Prof. Blatter. I hope that some English edition will appear soon :)